# Failed Building Wheel for gspread

Tags: google-api

Trying to access google sheets via api and everytime I try to install gspread, I get the "Failed building wheel for gspread" error.

I've tried
pip install gspread
pip install gspread --update

both giving me the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, try

```
pip install wheel
```

or

```
sudo pip install wheel
```